# How to sort students list according to their Marks using Insertion sort in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv, insertion-sort

I am trying to sort students list and rank each student according to their marks using insertion sort. Data of students include Name, Roll no, Address, Mark.

Here, I store the Mark of students in one list - `Marklist` and other data of students in a second list - `stdData`.

I sorted the student Mark List using Insertion sort. But right now I have 2 separate lists. How can I merge and print the sorted list of each student with their marks?

```
import csv
stdData = []  # store RollNum,student name last name,address
Marklist = []  # store the final mark of each student
#generallist=[]
with open("studentlist.csv", "r") as f1:
    recordReader = csv.DictReader(f1)
    for row in recordReader:
        #generallist.append(row)
        row['Mark']=int(row['Mark'])
        Marklist.append(row['Mark'])
        stdData.append(row['RollNo'])
        stdData.append(row['Name'])
        stdData.append(row['LastName'])
        stdData.append(row['Address'])
print(Marklist)
print(stdData)
for i in range(1, len(Marklist)):
    key = Marklist[i]
    j = i - 1
    while j >= 0 and key < Marklist[j]:
        Marklist[j + 1] = Marklist[j]
        j -= 1
    Marklist[j + 1] = key

   print("Sorted List: ",Marklist)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very near to the correct solution. The answer lies in

- Storing student details as list of list. Eg: `[ [student1 details], [student2 details], [student3 details] ]`
- sorting `stdData` using the indices of `MarkList`.

Below is the code modified to address the above points:

```
import csv
stdData = []  # store RollNum,student name last name,address
Marklist = []  # store the final mark of each student
generallist=[]
with open("studentlist.csv", "r") as f1:
    recordReader = csv.DictReader(f1)
    for row in recordReader:
        #generallist.append(row)
        row['Mark']=int(row['Mark'])
        Marklist.append(row['Mark'])
        tmp_data = []
        tmp_data.append(row['RollNo'])
        tmp_data.append(row['Name'])
        tmp_data.append(row['LastName'])
        tmp_data.append(row['Address'])
        stdData.append(tmp_data) # Storing student details as list of lists
print(Marklist)
print(stdData)
for i in range(1, len(Marklist)):
    key = Marklist[i]
    data = stdData[i] # Sort the elements in stdData using indices of MarkList
    j = i - 1
    while j >= 0 and key < Marklist[j]:
        Marklist[j + 1] = Marklist[j]
        stdData[j+1] = stdData[j]
        j -= 1
    Marklist[j + 1] = key
    stdData[j+1] = data
print("Sorted List: ",Marklist)
for student_data in stdData:
    print(student_data)
```

Even though the above solution gives the correct answer, it uses two lists.

We can sort a list using keys (need not to be actual list elements). The below code implements it and is a better solution.

```
import csv
stdData = []  # store RollNum,student name last name,address

with open("studentlist.csv", "r") as f1:
    recordReader = csv.DictReader(f1)
    for row in recordReader:
        tmp_data = []
        tmp_data.append(row['RollNo'])
        tmp_data.append(row['Name'])
        tmp_data.append(int(row['Mark']))
        tmp_data.append(row['LastName'])
        tmp_data.append(row['Address'])
        stdData.append(tmp_data) # Storing student details as list of lists

print(stdData)
for i in range(1, len(stdData)):
    key = stdData[i][2] # here the key is the mark
    data = stdData[i] # we will copy the data to correct index
    j = i - 1
    while j >= 0 and key < stdData[j][2]:
        stdData[j+1] = stdData[j]
        j -= 1
    stdData[j+1] = data

print("Sorted List:")
for rollno, name, mark, lastname, address in stdData:
    print(rollno, name, mark, lastname, address)
```

Happy coding.

Comment: The out put  is: 
Sorted List:  [56, 68, 78, 80, 81, 90]
['6', 'Milad', 'Shreyas', 'Mazar']
['1', 'Ahmed', 'Siraj', 'Kabul']
['2', 'Siraj', 'Aswin', 'Kabul']
['4', 'Preety', 'Rahul', 'Herat']
['5', 'Jan', 'Aswin', 'Herat']
['3', 'Mari', 'Aswin', 'Gazni'].  I want like this:                                                                                ['6', 'Milad', 'Shreyas', 'Mazar',56]
['1', 'Ahmed', 'Siraj', 'Kabul',68]
['2', 'Siraj', 'Aswin', 'Kabul',78]
['4', 'Preety', 'Rahul', 'Herat',80]
['5', 'Jan', 'Aswin', 'Herat',81]
['3', 'Mari', 'Aswin', 'Gazni.',90].

Comment: Isn't it the correct one? If not, can you tell me the expected output?

Comment: I want to add marklist to stdData and print sorted list.

Comment: Can you share a few samples from the input csv file as well?

Comment: RollNo,Name,LastName,Mark,Address
1,Ahmed,Siraj,68,Kabul
2,Siraj,Aswin,78,Kabul
3,Nafas,Aswin,90,Gazni
4,Preety,Rahul,80,Herat
5,Jan,Aswin,81,Herat
6,Milad,Shreyas,56,Mazar #this is my csv file

Comment: I think I found the problem. we just need to add : tmp_data.append(row['Mark']). add mark of students to tem_data. it will be the desired answer.

Comment: @Mina, I have modified the code and it is better as it uses only one list. If it solves the problem you are facing can you accept/upvote the answer?

Comment: I have updated my answer. The second code block is the modified code, which uses a list.

Comment: while j >= 0 and key < stdData[j][0]:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'. this error have print for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226964/discussion-between-mina-and-tpk).

Comment: my bad! `stdData[j][0]` is a string. It should have been `stdData[j][2]`. I have updated the solution